# Unknown provider: myFactProvider <- myFact <- thirdCtrl

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi all my requirement is to share input field data using get set method in factory with another controller.

```
angular.module('dataModule',[]).factory('myFact',function($http){
var user = {};
return {
   getDetails: function () {
       return user ;
   },
   setDetails : function (name,add,number) {
       user.name = name;
       user.add = add;
       user.number = number;
   }
}
});
```

Here is controller code.

```
angular.module('dataModule',[]).controller('thirdCtrl',function(myFact,$scope)  {
   $scope.saw=function(){
      alert("hello get set method");
      $scope.user=myFact.user.getDetails();
      console.log(user);
   };
});
```

Here is my html code

```
<div ng-controller="thirdCtrl">
   <h1>hello gaurav come here after click one.</h1>
   <div>
      <lable>NAME</lable>
      <div><input type="text"ng-model="user.name"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <lable>ADDRESS</lable>
      <div><input type="text"ng-model="user.add"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <lable>MOBILE</lable>
      <div><input type="number"ng-model="user.number"></div>
   </div>
   </br>
   </br>    
   <button type="button" ng-click="saw()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('sapient',['ui.router','dataModule']);
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('one', {
  url: '/one',
  templateUrl: 'view/sap.html',
  controller: 'sapCtrl'
})

.state('two', {
  url: '/two',
  templateUrl: 'view/two.html',
  controller: 'secondCtrl'
})


.state('three', {
  url: '/three',
  templateUrl: 'view/three.html',
  controller: 'thirdCtrl'
});     
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('two');
}])
```

Any Suggestions

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're recreating the module. Remove the `[]` (array of module dependencies) to make angular retrieve the previously created module, rather than create a new one.

Change:

```
angular.module('dataModule',[]).controller('thirdCtrl',function(myFact,$scope)
```

To:

```
angular.module('dataModule').controller('thirdCtrl',function(myFact,$scope)
```

Comment: first of all thinking you so much i remove array of dependency only from service not from controller . thanks man  you save my time .

Comment: No problem, yeah it depends which one you create first. You only have to create the module once (where it is first used). Thereafter, you're just retrieving it each time.